# Two-dimensional recurrence relation similar to that of Bessel numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I am trying to determine the solution for the two-dimensional recurrence relation
$$
C_{n+1,k}=C_{n,k}+nC_{n-1,k-1}
$$
I've noticed from [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82302626.pdf) (1.3) that this is very close to that of the Bessel numbers
$$
B_{n+1,k}=B_{n,k-1}+nB_{n-1,k-1}
$$
with the difference being the second index in the $n$ term.

Is there a resource which gives the solution to the first recurrence relation? Are they known by any name?

**EDIT**:
The initial values are $C_{n,0}=1$ and $C_{n,k}=0$ for $2k>n$.

Comment: It would be useful to give a table of the numbers for small values of $n,k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I plugged the numbers determined by your sequence, row by row, into OEIS, and found https://oeis.org/A100861, which gives the formula
$$
C_{n,k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-2k)!2^k}
$$
They are also called the Bessel numbers, and indeed each row is just a shift of the rows for $B_{n,k}$.